# Is there any way to use a template file for my all HTML pages?

Tags: html, css, templates

I am trying to design a web site. I am searching for a template to use on all of my pages, such as a news page, home page, about page, projects page, etc. I know that Dreamweaver has this feature, but is there any way to make it in my local workspace?

How can I have a logo or title in one place without copy and pasting it to every file?

Comment: the ww3school has a basic template for websites https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_band&stacked=h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little complex, but it will work on most, if not all, modern web servers. For testing, you'll have to look into something like IIS.

Create a header HTML page as `header.html` with your logo, title, navbar, et cetera. Then in any file you will have to write: `<?php include "header.html" ?>`

This won't work unless you download and install PHP and set up a localhost, something you can learn how to do [here](https://html5hive.org/how-to-setup-a-localhost/).

This might not qualify as a template, but will work for your purposes.

Comment: I created 2 page main.html and header.html as you said. But it did not worked.  I tried including just <?php include "header.html" ?> and including with html tags. By the way, I upload files to my ftp and tried from my main domain with chrome.

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan I might be missing a semicolon. If that fixed it, I'll edit my answer, but I don't think it will. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan Look at this W3Schools demo: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/showphp.asp?filename=demo_include1

Comment: I directly copy your code you can check it. [link](http://mahiryildizhan.com/main.html) and [link](http://mahiryildizhan.com/footer.php) but it's still does not work :(

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan You commented out the code. You used <-- instead of <?.

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan Interestingly, when I tried changing it with the inspect element tool, it reverted back to a comment. What hosting service are you using?

Comment: isimtescil.com, It's a basic linux server. A beginner package. But I know that PHP is working on it. Becouse I connected a page to MySQL before to learn.

Comment: Can you try editing the code so that the PHP isn't commented out? If it's not commented in you code, there's probably something wrong with the server.

Comment: I changed the main file with your name. Can you check the same main page?

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan I see the change. When I inspect the webpage in chrome or firefox, the PHP is commented out: `<!--?php include "footer.php" ?-->`

Comment: But the file which I sent is like <!DOCTYPE html>
`<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>This is a new try for Benoit. B. Mandelbrot</p>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>`  Is that means my server is not supporting the php? But as I told you, I use another pages which works.

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan That's not what shows up. It could be a server error. I don't think it's a browser error as it fails to work in Chrome and Firefox. Try an online free web hosting service to see.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to make and use templates (and themes), all depending on the technologies you're using, capable of doing or would like to use.

WYSIWYG website software like Dreamweaver provide features for making website templates and themes, but you'll likely be tied to using their proprietary system.

I think most professionals don't like to be locked to proprietary local software like that. Instead they use server-side CMS systems and/or client-side frameworks. Most beginner's probably get exposed to the concept of templates and themes via  the WordPress CMS, or via the basic CMS's you find at GoDaddy or Wix.

If you prefer to learn and code manually, and make your own system, that's great! There's tons of possibilities. Ultimately you'd be looking at using templates and/or themes, in one of two ways: Templates loaded client-side via a Javascript framework ... or ... templates loaded server-side via a CMS like WordPress.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I understood you. I just would like to learn is there any simple way to use a small template like nav bar. I just think about <iframe> tag for it and search on internet too long. But could not found anything. So I decided to write here.

Comment: Search Google for 'php include tutorial', that will get you started. PHP has a command called 'include' which allows you to inject external code at any point. You could make a nav.php file, that only contains your nav div's, which you can inject over and over into your various webpages using PHP include. This is probably the best way forward for you.

Comment: I understood. Thanks.